# make text center in each cell and fit table to the text width

Tags: pdftex

I have problem with fitting a table to the text width. For example in the below table, I want to fit the table width to the text and locate text in each cell in the centre. In this case, I used \centering command but it does not work.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
 \caption{Average Event-Driven Message Delivery Ratio for single-hop broadcasting}
\label{tab:table1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |p{1cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{2.7cm}|p{2.7cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Average Event-Driven Message Delivery Ratio (\%)}} \\
\hline
\textit{Vehicle ID} & \textit{IEEE802.11p} & \textit{Event TX in Dedicated Phase} & \textit{Event TX upon Token Reception} & \textit{Event TX Without Token}\\
\hline
1 & 77.00 & 87.00 & 95.25 & 88.25\\
\hline
2 & 84.00 & 87.00 & 96.25 & 87.25\\
\hline
3 & 85.00 & 87.00 & 97.00 & 87.00\\
\hline
4 & 83.00 & 87.00 & 96.50 & 88.25\\
\hline
5 & 77.00 & 87.00 & 96.00 & 89.87\\
\hline\hline
\textbf{Average} & \textbf{81.20} & \textbf{87.00} & \textbf{96.20} & \textbf{88.14}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code from `\documentclass` through `\end{document}` with the minimal additions needed to compile. How do we know how wide your text block is?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how wide your text block is as no minimal example was provided. So I've completed the code assuming A4 paper and the use of **geometry** without further options.

**tabularx** allows you to create tables which fill a given width - here, `\linewidth`. Don't use the `H` specifier. If you don't want a float, don't use `table` and use `\captionof` from **caption** or **capt-of**.

**array** is used for convenience, so we can create a custom version of the `X` column **tabularx** uses. The redefinition of the `X` column is from **tabularx**'s documentation.

I've also used **booktabs** to give the table a professional look. This means dispensing with vertical rules and using horizontal rules of varying widths. See the manual for details and further tips on producing high-quality tables.

I've removed the repetition of part of the caption in the table itself. Since this comes right after the caption, it is just distracting. I've added the percentage sign into the caption instead. This avoids using `\multicolumn` and permits more flexible specifications of the widths of the columns in the `tabularx` environment. See the manual for warnings and details about this.

Here's the result:

[image: result]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,array,geometry}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
%   \fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
  \caption{Average Event-Driven Message Delivery Ratio for single-hop broadcasting (\%)}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \par
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=.6\hsize}YY>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}Y>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}YY}
    \toprule
    \textit{Vehicle ID} & \textit{IEEE802.11p} & \textit{Event TX in Dedicated Phase} & \textit{Event TX upon Token Reception} & \textit{Event TX Without Token}\\
    \midrule
    1 & 77.00 & 87.00 & 95.25 & 88.25\\
    2 & 84.00 & 87.00 & 96.25 & 87.25\\
    3 & 85.00 & 87.00 & 97.00 & 87.00\\
    4 & 83.00 & 87.00 & 96.50 & 88.25\\
    5 & 77.00 & 87.00 & 96.00 & 89.87\\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Average} & \textbf{81.20} & \textbf{87.00} & \textbf{96.20} & \textbf{88.14}\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```